# How to listen to drag event of CytoscapeJS node (including only the one directly under the cursor/finger)

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using Cytoscape JS to create a web browser-based graph manipulation tool. I am facing a problem in listening the drag event of multiple selection of nodes.

I could listen to 'drag' event of nodes using the following code:

```
cy.on('drag', 'node', function (e) {
  let draggedNode = e.target
  ...
}
```

However, when I drag several nodes at once, the event is triggered to all selected nodes individually.

What I want to accomplish is to listen to drag event of a node where several nodes are currently selected, but only listen to the element directly (including only the one node directly under the cursor or the user’s finger). So that whenever I drag multiple selected nodes at once, the event only triggered to the one that being dragged under the finger or cursor only.

This is similar to `grabon`, `freeon` `dragfreeon` events that is currently available to CytoscapeJS. However, there is no `dragon` event for this. I don't want to listen to drag event of all currently selected node events. But only the one that is currently under the cursor/finger.

I have been trying to find the cursor position from the passed `e` parameter, so that I can test whether the cursor is currently over the current triggering node or not. However the `position` and `renderedPosition` attributes values were found to be `undefined`. So I can't do the cursor position test.

Therefore, is someone out there know how to implement this in Javascript? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `grabon`, `free` or similar to detect the target, add a class to it, and listen to `drag` events only for nodes of that class.

The `item.isNode()` check in the code below is kinda pointless.

```js
cy.on('grabon', 'node', (e) => {
    let item = e.target;

    if (item.isNode()) {
        item.addClass('drag-parent');
    }
});

cy.on('free', 'node', (e) => {
    let item = e.target;

    if (item.isNode() && item.hasClass('drag-parent')) {
        item.removeClass('drag-parent');
    }
})

cy.on('drag', 'node.drag-parent', (e) => {
    let item = e.target;

    console.warn(item.id());
})
```

Comment: I never thought that programmatically adding class to a node is possible that way. It's a working implementation alternative to `dragon` event which is not currently exists. One thing to note is to make sure that the additional code on `grabon`, `free`, `drag` event listener don't interfere with current existing implementation, especially if you are trying to implement complex functionality. Thanks.