# Find selected nodes/edges in cytoscape.js "on('unselect')" event

Tags: cytoscape.js

**Background**

When I tap a node, one event fires; the 'tap' event. When I then tap a different node, two events fire; the 'tap' event, then the 'unselect' event.

At first I thought it was a problem with `on('tap')` and `on('unselect')` event order, just because a human might think, "first I'm clearing my selection, and then I'm selecting a new node", but I can see why this is functioning as it should. A different node is tapped, so the 'tap' event fires; and then because the previous node is no longer selected, the 'unselect' event fires.

So, I think that it is working as it should, but its does mean that I need to code around this behaviour.

**Details**

What I want to do is to call some code in `on('unselect')` that will only run when no node/edge is selected. That would usually be when I click the background of the graph.

The problem is that `cy.$('node:selected').length` is always returning 0. And the same for `edge:selected`. See the below code.

So I'd just like to know if there are any workarounds for this? How can I query a graph's selected items in `on('unselect')`?

**Context**

I'm using the graph selection to filter the rows of a table, but when no node/edge is selected, I want the table to show all the data. Currently, each node/edge must be clicked twice for the `on('tap')` to not be overwritten by the `on('unselect')` unfilter code.

**Steps to reproduce**

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  elements: [
    { data: { id: 'a' } },
    { data: { id: 'b' } },
    { data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' } }
  ]
});
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  console.log('event: tap node');
});
cy.on('tap', 'edge', function(evt){
  console.log('event: tap edge');
});
cy.on('unselect', function(evt){
  console.log('event: unselect');
  console.log('node:  ' + cy.$('node:selected').length);
  console.log('edge:  ' + cy.$('edge:selected').length);
});
```

When I tap a node, console logs the tap.
When I tap a different node, console logs the tap, then logs the unselect.

So when I click a node, then an edge, then a node, then the background, the console log is:

```
event: tap node
event: tap edge
event: unselect
node:  0
edge:  0
event: tap node
event: unselect
node:  0
edge:  0
event: unselect
node:  0
edge:  0
```

As you can see, `cy.$('node:selected').length` is always 0.

**Environment info**

Cytoscape.js version: 3.15.0

Answer (score 1):

Same principle as [How to listen to drag event of CytoscapeJS node (including only the one directly under the cursor/finger)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380170/how-to-listen-to-drag-event-of-cytoscapejs-node-including-only-the-one-directly)

Add a class of your choice, like `.selected` to the target(s) on `tap` and use that class when listening for `unselect` events or when querying for selected targets. Remove the class within your `unselect` handler logic, so no `.selected` targets stick around.